# Problems enabling BitLocker on Windows 7 enterprise

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I had BitLocker turned on originally when I loaded the computer but had to turn it off to do some testing. I recently tried to turn it back on and I continue to get the following error:

> A required TPM measurement is missing.
>   If there is a bootable CD or DVD in 
>   your computer, remove it, restart the
>   computer, and turn on BitLocker again.
>   If the problem persists, ensure the
>   master boot record is up to date.

I have verified that there is nothing in the DVD tray and that the laptop is not docked. I have also verified that TPM is running and I have no problems enabling BitLocker on a flash drive. I think it's a problem with my MBR since I am dual booting into Fedora as well but I am not sure how to fix it. (even though it did work a few months ago while I was also dual booted) Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Windows was unable to find the correct boot partition since Grub was installed. I originally tried to boot with a Win 7 DVD and run fixmbr, but after I did that I couldn't boot at all. I then used GParted and changed the boot flag from my grub partition to my Windows boot partition and it worked fine.